# Неявный вызов конструктора копирования

Tags: c++, классы, наследование

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() { std::cout << 'A'; }
    A(const A&) { std::cout << 'a'; }
};

struct B : A {
    B() { std::cout << 'B'; }
    B(const B&) { std::cout << 'b'; }
};

int main() {
    B b1;
    B b2{b1};
}
```

Почему программа выводит

> ABAb

а не ожидаемое мной

> ABab

Почему разработчики стандарта решили именно такое поведение установить?

Comment: Потому что конструктор `A(const A&)` в приведенном примере нигде не используется. Вы могли бы легко в этом убедится, написав его как `A(const A&) = delete;`

Comment: @user7860670 понятно, что не используется, раз не выводит. Но почему?

Comment: Ну это к вам вопрос, почему вы его не используете? Конструктор без параметров `A()` называется конструктором по-умолчанию не без причины, он вызывается каждый раз, когда при создании объекта не вызывается какой-то другой конструктор. Никакого конструктора подобъекта А в объекте B вы не вызываете, следовательно вызывается конструктор по-молчанию.

Comment: @user7860670 "он вызывается каждый раз, когда при создании объекта не вызывается какой-то другой конструктор" - почему так? Не логичнее ли вызывать конструктор по-умолчанию у базового класса, когда вызывается конструктор по-умолчанию, а когда вызывается конструктор копирования, то вызывать конструктор копирования базовый?

Comment: Нет, не логичнее. Вызов конструктора по-умолчанию (и деструктора) не требует передачи аргумента (который в этом коде даже не обозначен). А еще бывает конструктор перемещения, для которого по такой логике потребовалось не только неявно передавать аргумент, но и предварительно кастовать его в rvalue. Хотя бы в чем-то С++ консистентен.

Comment: @user7860670 так консистентность копирование -> копирование, по-умолчанию -> по-умолчанию нарушена. Это смотря с какой стороны посмотреть

Comment: @user7860670 я думаю тут есть какая-то проблема, раз не сделали более очевидный вариант. Круто если бы кто-то её указал.

Comment: нет, не так. Сейчас консистентность отсутствие явного вызова конструктора -> вызов конструктора по-умолчанию. А в вашем случае получается отсутствие явного вызова конструктора во всех ситуациях кроме отсутствия вызова конструктора не виртуального базового подобъекта в определенном пользователем конструкторе, подпадающим под категорию конструктор копирования -> вызов конструктора по-умолчанию ... Еще применительно к примеру из вопроса тут был бы казус в том, что обычно к сущности без имени (аргумент в данном случае) нельзя обратится, а тут было бы неявное обращение для передачи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз вы не указали конструктор для базового класса `A` явно:

```
B(const B&) { std::cout << "b"; }
```

компилятор вызывает конструктор по умолчанию.

Если напишете

```
B(const B&b):A(b) { std::cout << "b"; }
```

то получите ожидаемую вами строку.

Comment: Почему в `B b1;` не надо явно указывать, а в `B b2{b1};` надо?

Comment: @bezos конструктор по умолчанию также и вызывает конструктор по умолчанию родительский также по дефолту если иного не указать

Comment: @Ildar так а почему контруктор копирования не вызывает родительский конструктор копирования по-умолчанию?

Comment: @bezos при переопределении других конструкторов надо явно указывать какие конструкторы нужны, иначе конструктор по умолчанию везде вызывается

Comment: @Ildar почему так?

Comment: @bezos такое вот поведение по умолчанию, так заложено

Comment: @Ildar мне интересно почему так заложено. Разработчики стандарта сели и решили "а давайте вызывать НЕ конструктор копирования а другой конструктор в конструкторе копирования, звучит клёва"?

Comment: *почему в B b1; не надо явно указывать* - почему же не надо? Не надо, если вас устраивает конструктор по умолчанию... Но вы можете указать любой другой. Что до *Разработчики стандарта сели и решили "а давайте вызывать НЕ конструктор копирования а другой конструктор в конструкторе копирования, звучит клёва"* - они всего лишь решили, что сгенерированный конструктор копирования будет вызывать конструктор копирования, а уж если вы сами решили, что простое почленное копирование для вас не годится - то предоставьте его сами...